# Image priority Java

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm putting images on my `JFrame` using `ImageIcon` and then, to display the images:

```
getContentPane().add(label[3]);                                
getContentPane().add(label[2]);         
getContentPane().add(label[1]);
```

Now Image 3 will have priority over 2 and 2 over 1 etc
Is there anyway to set the priority or reverse it so the last image I put on screen will have priority over the other images?

Comment: What do you mean by priority? Higher priority should appear above others?

Comment: The image that is display on top of the others - I want the last image I put on screen to have priority not the first???

Comment: Not sure what you really wants.

Comment: Do any of the images have transparency? Is the desired effect to overlay the series of images so parts of each are visible within the same space? Any which way, I suspect you are going about it the wrong way, and unclear on what end effect is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all, if you want to put the images along a third dimension axis, you should take a look at [this layered panes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).
From the official documentation:

> A layered pane is a Swing container that provides a third dimension
>   for positioning components: depth, also known as Z order. When adding
>   a component to a layered pane, you specify its depth as an integer.
>   The higher the number, closer the component is to the "top" position
>   within the container. If components overlap, the "closer" components
>   are drawn on top of components at a lower depth. The relationship
>   between components at the same depth is determined by their positions
>   within the depth.

As shown in this image, you should be able to position your components on the top of the others.

If this does not meet your requirement, please edit your question to be more specific.

[image: Layered pane screenshot]

Comment: Thank  you I think this is it :)

Comment: @Mharles Canson I'm glad to hear that. Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you :)